# Is there a way to pre-render a virtual panoramic scene?

Tags: algorithm, ipad, 3d, panoramas

I would like to put a photorealistic virtual scene on a tablet so when the user rotates the tablet, it shows as if the tablet is a window to an virtual world.

Pre-rendered scenes can be rendered photorealistic, while real-time rendering has a "computer-made look". Given that for one scene, the POV can be rotated but not translated in space, is it possible that a pre-rendered virtual panoramic scene give an immersive impression?
I doubt that this is easy, since rotating the view point will cause some sort of distortion. This kind of distortion is easy for apps like Starwalk, but difficult for photos. Can anyone point me out a direction?

I know that this will be tremendously easy for restricting motion in only one direction, but I would like the user to have a full 3d experience.

Comment: *Pre-rendered scenes can be rendered photorealistic, while real-time rendering has a "computer-made look".* This is not really related; it's just a matter of how much computer resources you can sink in and how realistic the artist's skills are and the technology you're using. With effort you can make a real-time rendered raytraced scene that is millions of times more "photorealistic" than a pre-rendered junky image. Also photos are more realistic than non-photos.

Comment: Read the first sentence. This is on a tablet. What I mean by pre-rendered is a raytraced scene rendered on another manchine.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that http://code.google.com/p/panoramagl/ can render cubic, spherical and cylindrical panoramic images, so the problem transforms to how to make render a panorama which can be solved by stitching. I will still leave this answer open to see if anyone else has better answers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either warp the photographs before applying them as textures to your "sky dome" or use non uniform texture coordinates. If done right this will even out most of the distortions giving a more realistic appearance.

Another alternative is to use more photographs so that you are only actually using the central area of each one.